# About jQuery.Deferred()

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm studying some use-case in Deferred, and I came by this instruction:

```
$.Deferred().reject().promise()
```

I don't get it, under what condition we call `reject()` then directly we call `promise()`?

I mean, if we want to reject the deferred object, how can the rejected deferred represent a promise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we call `.reject()` and then `.promise()`, we are returning a promise that we have already decided will not succeed. Any handlers bound with `.fail()` or `.always()` will be immediately invoked upon them being added.

Comment: Does this mean that if we want any handlers bound with `.done()` to be invoked immediately, we call `$.Deferred.resolve().prmoise()`?